# ng build --prod is extremely slow

Tags: angular, angular-cli

We have an Angular project, and we're trying to build it with `--prod` option.

The problem is, it took 33 hours!

To be honest, we're not that good with Angular, npm and all that, we're all beginners in this world.

All we know, is when we execute the `ng build --prod command`, we get stuck in here for hours:

```
11% building modules 9/11 modules 2 active …s\font-awesome\css\font-awesome.min.css
```

We tried removing the font-awesome.min.css from the `angular.json` file, well we get stuck in another CSS file, and it never ends. Even when we removed all the CSS files from the `angular.json` file, we get stuck here:

```
10% building modules 2/2 modules 0 active
```

Here are our versions:

```
Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.7.5
@angular-devkit/core               0.7.5
@angular-devkit/schematics         0.8.9
@angular/cdk                       6.4.7
@angular/cli                       6.2.9
@angular/material                  6.4.7
@ngtools/json-schema               1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                   6.1.5
@schematics/angular                0.8.9
@schematics/update                 0.8.9
ng-packagr                         4.7.1
rxjs                               6.4.0
typescript                         2.9.2
webpack                            4.9.2
```

All we want, is to find a way to debug this problem, or maybe someone already experienced the same problem?

Here are my computed specs:

```
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz 3.19 GHz
RAM: 32Gb
Windows 7
```

Comment: I don't angular but I think that might be because of low ram or processing speed of your computer. Can you add your computer specifications

Comment: Updated with my computer specs. We have the some problem on several computers.

Comment: try putting '--no-aot' flag, read more here about the flag before using it:  https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

Comment: Wow, `ng build --prod --no-aot --build-optimizer false` worked perfectly in less than a minute, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -22, accepted):

For your information:

```
ng build --prod --no-aot --build-optimizer false
```

Worked in less than a minute.

Comment: You're removing important settings of the Prod build. Of course it'll be faster.

Comment: Removing features is NOT the same as fixing issues.

Comment: But that was the issue i mean, i never said i needed those features, i just wanted it to be fast ...

Comment: The intent of building for prod is to have these important settings.

Comment: not building is another option if this is your solution

Comment: This should be unmarked as the answer, it isn't. It is disabling features that are important in prod builds.

Comment: optimization = true option is taking too long, even on a high config machine. Any way to improve this build?

Answer (score 10):

Increasing node's allotted memory size really sped things up for me.
You can see here I gave it an entire 8GB as opposed to the default 512MB.

```
> node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

If you are unsure of how much memory your machine has available use the following command to see memory stats based on MB, check under the `available` column not the `free` column.

```
> free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15866        1490        3726         116       10650       13929
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was calling ng build from a batch file. It took forever to build. It was very fast in Jetbrains Webstorm terminal.I then tried to run main batch file from Windows powershell and it worked.